# connecting onedrive api to database

Tags: java, onedrive

I have a problem where I am supposed to create an application (Preferably Java) which extracts data (Excel sheet) from onedrive account of different users and store that in a database.
I went through different resources on internet to look for the same. But i couldn't find any REST API for JAVA Applications (Although there is for Android).

Any pointers in solving above problem would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Excel Datasource

As much of a fan as I am of OneDrive, it is really about storing file information not relational data.  It sounds like your problem would be best solved with a connected Excel data source as seen below in this example.  This will require that you setup an accessible datasource (Setting up a DB, API, or file backed source).   Using the following menu should allow you to creation the relationship with the excel presentation.

[image: Excel Data Sources]

## Straight-forwards APIs

Assuming that you don't have the time/control needed to architect a completely new way of using this content I can give you some basic pointers around the following scenarios, 1 getting an up-to-date file from OneDrive, 2 interacting with the excel data and 3 then naturally doing what you need to do with that information.

1) Working with OneDrive

- If you can interact with the file inside of your OneDrive using your machine, install the [sync client for OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/).  This will work on a Mac, Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 machine and might just get you up and syncing with ease.
- If you can't use your personal account/deploy to a controlled machine you will want to use and SDK like the LiveSDK.  However, I would actually recommend the [Live-SDK-for-Windows](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows), while it is not java, C# is pretty close in a lot of ways as long as you can depend on running on a windows machine.
- Lastly, if you need to be able to run in a non-windows environment or have to run using the Java stack then I'd say that you should look at porting the [LiveSDK-for-Android](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android) into a java only version, this is a large amount of work as you'll need to remove all the android dependencies, but you should be able to target your specific scenario around getting/updating files.   You could technically look at reverse engineering how the service interactions work with a program like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler).

2) Interacting with Excel files

- Look around the [Excel SDKs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179694(v=office.15).aspx) these are your best functionality bets to dig into your spreadsheets and getting the data that you'll need.  There is a high likelihood that you will need to use C# or a .Net language to use them however.
- Find a java compatible library to use, a quick Bing search turned up [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/excel_example.html), note that this still requires a Windows environment for execution and will have their own restrictions and usages.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I agree with you that Excel should not be used to store relational data. My problem is that there are certain users who continuously update information on daily basis in an excel sheet. So i need to write "some job" which access their one drive periodically, gets excel data and then move it to SQL database.

Comment: I saw Onedrive API. I have never interacted/used APIs before. To me it seems that, we need to create some application which gets permission from user to access their onedrive. But I have no intention of creating such application. My problem is to just create a background job to access onedrive, so not sure how would i be able to access these accounts.

Comment: I appreciate that you don't want to build a 'full application' but you will need some kind of glue to link your experiences together.  If you want to create a lighter weight 'application' glue here is some details on how to use powershell to interact with OneDrive; however, I cannot vouch for the ease in connecting up the Office integration that you desire.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/02/use-powershell-to-work-with-skydrive-for-powerful-automation.aspx

Comment: As I am using Linux machine,I am not sure if i can use powershell. I tried downloading file using CURL, but I am not able to go beyond login page. This is my command.
`curl -O -L --sslv3 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13" --user Myusername:Mypassword 'https://OurDomain.sharepoint.com/_%7BB21r-9CA2-345DEF%7D&file=IPS_cleaned.xlsx&action=default'`
Appreciate your help

Comment: After using above command, it downloads a html file which when opened, shows sharepoint login page. I guess it is not able to go beyond authentication.